# PHP / SQL incrementing/decrementing database column by variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am aware that there are several questions with answers like this one, but for a weird reason I don't know, none of those seem to solve my problem. I get no errors when I use the code I have, but the values in my database doesn't seem to get updated.

```
$outcomeNum = rand(14, 19);
if (checkRandom($chance['1'])) {
    echo "You took the hobos cup and you earned " . $outcomeNum . " dollars.";
    $data->query("UPDATE players SET money = (money + $outcomeNum) WHERE id = '".$id."'");
} else {
    if (checkRandom(25)) {
        echo "You thought twice about it when you was sent a creepy look from the hobo.";
    } else {
        echo "You got beaten up by the hobo and you lost " . $outcomeNum . " health.";
        $data->query("UPDATE players SET health = (health - $outcomeNum) WHERE id = '".$id."'");
    }
}
```

Comment: Enable error_reporting.

Comment: What database extension are you using? Does your database class report database errors?

Comment: Why such an inconsistent coding style? Why do you use variable interpolation for `$outcome`, but concatenation for `$id`?

Comment: I tried what someone else did in another question to try and see if it would work.

Comment: I don't see any obvious problems in any of the queries. If you print out the query strings before executing them, do they look right?

Comment: @1nflktd error_reporting is enabled.

Comment: The syntax and everything looks correct. What exactly is `$data` and does `$data` *work* as expected besides the `UPDATE`s ?

Comment: @Barmar They do. I have been stuck with this issue for a week now. I do not see the problem either.

Comment: @DanFromGermany $data is my mysqli_ thingy. It works perfectly for me when used elsewhere in my file.

Comment: It's not working no matter which case in the `if` it chooses?

Comment: Is the code you show wrapped in a function?

Comment: $val = "UPDATE players SET money = (money + $outcomeNum) WHERE id = '".$id."'";
print $val;
$data->query($val).  Maybe try something like this for troubleshooting to see if the query you're executing looks like you expect it to, then run this manually on your DB to see the results

Comment: @Barmar Neither of them works.

Comment: Does your class print `mysqli_error()` when there's an error?

Comment: @DaOgre Weirdly enough, it won't print out $val.

Comment: @Barmar I think so, yes.

Comment: To stop the guessing, please look into your PHP error log. The error is possibly at a very different position in your code.

Comment: That makes no sense. It prints out the `You took the cup` message, but not `$val`?

Comment: @DanFromGermany No errors in my error log for this file.

Comment: Running the query from phpMyAdmin works flawlessly.

Comment: Then look at my third point: create an `$sql` variable and echo it.

Comment: Already tried it. It doesn't echo it.

Comment: var_dump the vars and the sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Work out which query doesn't run
- Run the expected SQL query in phpMyAdmin
- If no errors, create an `$sql` variable and echo it.

Comment: This is not an answer and almost the exact same thing has been posted by DaOgre.

Comment: @DanFromGermany there was no way to know what was causing the error without the OP doing these checks. The question was effectively, "there are no errors, what do I do?" and my answer is what it is.